# How do i make image bigger using setimage discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've tried to set images into my embed like this:
`Embed.setImage(bot.users.cache.get(User.id).displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}), 200, 200);`
it works perfectly fine, but honestly the image is small when displayed on discord.
does anyone know how to make it bigger?
I have searched everywhere and couldn't find any docs that tells me how to set it. I've seen bots display my avatar bigger than my bot does.

I will be thankful for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you code either rewrite the image with node-canvas or use the size attribute when getting `displayAvatarURL` stated here:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ImageURLOptions

```js
//if User is a instance of a user class and it's not partial why not 
//just use User.displayAvatarURL() ?
const user = bot.users.cache.get(User.id);
const url = user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 256});
new MessageEmbed()
   .setImage(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have experienced avatars that are usually small ( if the users have a cropped image) the image will be small
I used this-

```
.setImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL({size:1024,dynamic:true}))
```